# Programmatically create taxonomy term

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

How would you programmatically create taxonomy term? I wish to bulk create some in a custom module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll want to use [taxonomy_save_term](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_save_term/6). The array you pass in to taxonomy_save_term should look like this.

```
$term = array(
 'name' => 'Taxonomy Term 1',
 'vid' => 1, // The VID of the vocabulary this term should be saved under
 'description' => 'A description of this term', // Not required
 'weight' => 5, // Not required
);
taxonomy_save_term($term);
```

Comment: 'weight' can also be included here

Comment: There is also parent, relations, and synonyms but I didn't feel those were as important ;)

Comment: @Shaoib: did you know that you can edit answers on stackexchange, and enhance the answer with your knowledge? I added the weight property and also finished up the code example with a taxonomy_save_term() call.

Comment: [Term creation for Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79977/create-taxonomy-term-with-code)