# Create taxonomy term with code

Tags: hooks

I want to know how i can create taxonomy term programmatically.

I have this code

```
$term = new stdClass();
$term->name = ‘Term Name’;
$term->vid = 1; // ‘1’ is a vocabulary id you wish this term to assign to
$term->field_custom_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = ‘Some value’; // OPTIONAL. If your term has a custom field attached it can added as simple as this
taxonomy_term_save($term); // Finally, save our term
```

From [Link](http://popthestash.com/2012/06/09/how-to-programmatically-create-nodes-and-taxonomies-in-drupal-7/)

I don't know where to write it. I think it will be in template.php with some hook ?

Drupal 7

Comment: What event are you wishing to react to?

Comment: Just to import through code some taxonomy terms so i don't have to do it via GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to run an arbitrary PHP script through Drupal, the easiest way is probably using the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel)

It provides a page (/devel/php) where you can copy/paste PHP code and have it run inside a fully bootstrapped instance of Drupal.

Comment: This is awesome!